# jUnit loads another Class compared to WebApp runtime

Tags: maven, junit, cron, tomcat7, jakarta-mail

I'm working on a feature, where a Cron Job will trigger a connection through javax.mail, and scan all the incoming mails of a certain IMAP account.

It's a part of a Liferay Portlet, built with JSF-2 and Maven, and deployed on a Tomcat server.

I've built a jUnit Test that executes this scenario successfully, running the exact same function that would be called from the the Cron Job. I did this test by executing the `maven build package` target, and my Maven is using the same JVM with my Tomcat.

But after deploying the WebApp in the server and the Cron Trigger kicks in, I'm getting this error:

```
    org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:224)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:321)
    at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:361)
```

So I guess that under the Tomcat Runtime or Servlet Context or the quartz flow or whatever, there is a different resolution of `com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger`, compared to the resolution of jUnit.

Why is this happening, and how can I make sure I'm loading the correct Class  in all scenarios?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple versions of JavaMail in you classpath.  One that is Javamail 1.4.5 or older and one that is JavaMail 1.4.6 or newer.

Comment: @jmehrens You're right, my tomcat was using an older version. However I tried using the exact same version, and there was still a problem. Check my answer for more.

Comment: Is there a new error message?

Comment: not sure, If this is important for you I can try reproducing this in the next days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By tracing the error, I found out that a different version of `javax.mail` was loaded from `tomcat/ext/lib`, and overriding mine, when the server was running and the flow was initiated in Server Context.

Finally, I managed to deal with this problem, by changing my javax.mail-api dependency from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I switched to an older javax.mail-api version, compatible with the server's one, and I'm also using the library that is provided in the runtime